# Querying a value from an XML in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am struggling with querying a value from an XML. I am new in this world so please forgive me if the answer is actually obvious and i am just not seeing it :)

```
<documentid>
    <id accountingentity="200" lid="...."
        variationid="6370">aa0000012</id>
</documentid>
```

I want to query the value "aa0000012" but I am not able to do it since there is no Xpath for this value available.

I tried it with this query right here but it is only giving me the whole content:

```
select
    @salesorderxml.query('/syncsalesorder/dataarea/salesorder/salesorderheader/documentid/id')
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should work whether you have multiple documentid's or not

```
select  o.value('id[1]', 'varchar(max)')
from    @salesorderxml.nodes('/documentid') as t(o)
```

it basically says give me the nodes named `documentid`, then give me the value of element `id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it will reach into the XML and fetch the element value of `<id>`:

```
SELECT
    XC.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM
    @salesorderxml.nodes('/documentid/id') AS XT(XC)
```

This returns:

```
(No column name)
----------------
aa0000012
```